# Is this Structure for Servlet JSP application correct?

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am building a servlet app to run on tomcat server. However when i was not able to update the jsp page using:

```
request.setAttribute("operation", "op_name");
request.getRequestDispatcher("\WEB-INF\index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

404 index.jsp not found comes.

I think that servlet and web elements like jsp are in different paths that's why it is going wrong. So do i need to make another project using maven structure like having src\main\java etc. or this structure is also fine? Also how to update the index.jsp using this structure?

[image: Project Folder Structure]

Comment: no need to add `\WEB-INF`
request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);

Comment: @swarooppallapothu no same 404 not found comes still

Comment: Can you check in browser address bar with url + '/' contextpath + '/' index.jsp

Comment: keep that `index.jsp` outside of `\WEB-INF` (within web content) and re-deploy